# Research Problem about Weakly Supervised Learning for CT Image Semantic Segmentation

Tags: neural-networks, classification, computer-vision, image-segmentation

My issue is that Grad-CAM often highlights the wrong areas. My task is to perform weakly supervised semantic segmentation (WSSS) of lung malignant tumors using image-level labels. Although I achieved excellent performance on both the training and testing sets, with high accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 scores all close to 100%, the Grad-CAM results are not very accurate. I used the basic ResNet18 model and the pytorch-grad-cam library to generate the Grad-CAM visualizations. My dataset consists of around 1000 CT images, with 50% normal lungs and 50% malignant tumors, and I split the data into a 90:10 training-testing ratio. I suspect that the reason for the inaccurate Grad-CAM results is that the dataset may not be sufficient for the model to learn meaningful information.

The sample Grad-CAMs from my data are displayed below. As you can see, the Grad-CAM visualizations are significantly inaccurate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This questions seems more about image classification than Weakly Supervised Semantic Segmentation (even if that is your final goal). However, how can you obtain such a high accuracy on test set if you state that "your model does not learn any meaningful information"? Did you check if that area can be used by your model to "cheat" i.e it differs between positive/negative images ?